# Adding rel="lightbox" attribute to javascript generated image link

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, wordpress

I guess there is an easy solution to this, but javascript is NOT my strong side. This is a part of a script made for swapping product variation images (thumbs) in WP E-commerce.

My lightbox effects works for the main product image, but I can't get it working on the swapped thumbnails (which is shown/hidden by simply adding/removing a .hidden class with JS).

How can I add rel="lightbox" to the link in the swapped images? See code below:

```
jQuery(function($){
$("div.wpsc_variation_forms select.wpsc_select_variation").change(function() {
    var productForm = $(this).parents("form.product_form");

    var data = {
        action: 'get_variation_image_url',
        form_values: $("input[name=product_id],div.wpsc_variation_forms select.wpsc_select_variation", productForm).serialize()
    };

    var productColumn = productForm.parent(".productcol");
    var imageColumn = productColumn.siblings("div.imagecol");

    imageColumn.css("opacity", 0.5);

    jQuery.post(wpsc_ajax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        var data = $(response.split(/\n/));

        if(response == ""){
            data = $([]);
        }

        var images = imageColumn.children();

        if(images.length == 0){
            imageColumn.css("opacity", 1);
            return;
        }

        var hiddenImages = images.filter(".hidden");
        var visibleImages = images.not(".hidden");

        var imageColumnContainsVariationImages = hiddenImages.length > 0;

        if(imageColumnContainsVariationImages){
            var variationImages = visibleImages;
            variationImages.remove();
        } else {
            var originalImages = visibleImages;
            originalImages.hide().addClass("hidden");
        }

        var newVariationImageShouldBeAdded = data.length > 0;

        if(newVariationImageShouldBeAdded){
            data.each(function(){
                var imageUrl = this.split("***");
                var imageLink = images.first().clone(true).removeClass("hidden");

                imageLink.attr("href", imageUrl[0]);

                var image = imageLink.find("img");
                image.removeAttr("src");
                image.attr("src", imageUrl[1]);

                imageLink.show().appendTo(imageColumn);
            });
        } else {
            images.show().removeClass("hidden");
        }

        imageColumn.css("opacity", 1);
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance, you are the best!

Comment: :share some HTML markup.Were you want to add 'rel' which element

Comment: The output should be like this:
`<a href="bigimage.jpg" rel="ligtbox"><img src="thumb.jpg"></a>`

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
imageLink.attr("rel", "lightbox");
```

EDIT: I think you will need to re-apply the plugin to the cloned element:

```
imageLink.attr("rel", "lightbox").lightbox();
```

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but I does not seem to be working properly (it just opens the big image in a new window w/o the lightbox effect).

Comment: @Eirik - I think the plugin needs to be reapplied, please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks Karim, but I'm afraid it didn't work. Actually the swapped image did not show up at all after adding this to the code. PS: I've added the complete plugin script in my original post now.

Comment: @Eirik - Okay, last idea, try applying the plugin after the image has been appended to the DOM: `imageLink.show().appendTo(imageColumn).lightbox()`

Answer (score 1):

It's another attribute, so you can use `.attr` as well. `.attr` also supports passing multiple attributes as an object. You could also combine the chaining. Lastly, `.attr` overwrites existing attributes, so `.removeAttr` is superfluous.

```
if(newVariationImageShouldBeAdded){
        data.each(function(){
            var imageUrl = this.split("***");

            var imageLink = images.first()
                                  .clone(true)
                                  .removeClass("hidden")
                                  .attr({ href: imageUrl[0],
                                          rel:  "lightbox" })
                                  .show()
                                  .appendTo(imageColumn);

            var image = imageLink.find("img")
                                 .attr("src", imageUrl[1]);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
if (newVariationImageShouldBeAdded) {
    data.each(function() {
        var imageUrl = this.split("***"),
            imageLink = images.first().clone(true).removeClass("hidden");

        imageLink.attr("href", imageUrl[0]);

        var image = imageLink.find("img");
        image.removeAttr("src");
        image.attr("src", imageUrl[1]);
        image.attr("rel", "lightbox");

        imageLink.show().appendTo(imageColumn);
    });
}
```

Let me know if thats ok - would maybe need to take a look at other code if it didn't?

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. The big image just opens up in a blank new window, no lightbox effect applied.

Comment: Could we take a look at the page that the code is being run on?